# Problema com os xticks - matplotlib

Tags: python, data, pandas, matplotlib, ciência-de-dados

Sou iniciante na área de data science e estou desenvolvendo minha solução para o problema do titanic no Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic).

No momento estou criando uma visualização para para verificar a correlação entre features do conjunto de treino com a sobrevivência do passageiro.

Atualmente o conjunto de treino está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E utilizando o seguinte código

```
# Alterando a fonte
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Helvetica'

# Alterando o estilo dos eixos
plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor']='#333F4B'
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth']=0.8
plt.rcParams['xtick.color']='#333F4B'
plt.rcParams['ytick.color']='#333F4B'

# Criando os bar plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4)
fig.set_size_inches(15, 9)
df_column = 0
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(4):
        survival_correlation = pd.DataFrame(train_df[[train_df.columns[1:].tolist()[df_column], 
                                                  'Survived']].groupby([train_df.columns[1:].tolist()[df_column]], 
                                                                             as_index=False).mean().iloc[:, 1].values)
        my_range=list(range(len(survival_correlation)))
        ax[row, col].hlines(y=my_range, xmin=0, xmax=survival_correlation, color='#007ACC', alpha=0.2, linewidth=5)
        ax[row, col].plot(survival_correlation, my_range, "o", markersize=5, color='#007ACC', alpha=0.6)
        ax[row, col].set_xticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
        ax[row, col].set_yticks(np.arange(len(survival_correlation)))

        # Alterando o estilo das labels
        ax[row, col].set_xlabel('Média de sobrêvivencia', color = '#333F4B')
        ax[row, col].set_ylabel(train_df.columns[1:].tolist()[df_column])

        # Retirando os limites de cima e da direita do gráfico
        ax[row, col].spines['top'].set_color('none')
        ax[row, col].spines['right'].set_color('none')
        ax[row, col].spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
        ax[row, col].spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
        df_column += 1

plt.show()
```

Eu criei essa visualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, apesar de usar o método *set_xticks* o eixo x vai apenas até a porcentagem máxima da feature.
Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que o eixo x tenha 1 como valor máximo.

**OBS**: sei que alterando o parâmetro *xmax* de *hlines* eu consigo que o eixo x vá até 1, no entanto isso faz com que o gráfico fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: usa o método plt.xlim(), assim vai limitar para o número que você quer, para usar vai dois números, o mínimo e o máximo -> plt.xlim(0,1)

Comment: agora se vc quer controlar os valores que aparecem no eixos, usa o plt.xticks([]), onde na lista ([]) vc coloca os números que vc quer que apareça